# How to Declare Different Characters for Same Variable in a For Loop

Tags: javascript, string, variables, for-loop

I am trying to learn loops and strings in Javascript, and was wondering if it is possible to declare different characters for a variable in a loop. For example, I know that I can have a code like:

```
 for (var i = 0 ; char && (i < str.length) ; i++) {
   if (i == 3 || i == 7)  char = '-' ==  str.charAt(i) }
```

but if I wanted to allow for different characters in certain parts of a string (such as variable `char` equaling both a `{` if `i == 2` while also equaling a `}` if `i == 6`) such as:

```
var char = 12 == str.length ;
for (var i = 0 ; char && (i < str.length) ; i++) {
    if (i === 2) char = '{' ==  str.charAt(i)
```

While also allowing for:

```
if (i === 6) char = '}' ==  str.charAt(i)
```

So, essentially, is it possible to have a single string be able to allow different characters in set positions? If not, any ideas on how to enact something similar? I hope this makes sense, I wasn't entirely sure how to best phrase this question.

Clarification edit: if I programmed something allowing users to type something in, but it only allows for certain characters to be typed in certain spots.

Comment: `3 === i` and `7 === i` should be `i === 3` and `i === 7`. Also, don't take advantage of the optional `{}` when statements have just one line of code following them. Always bracket off your branches.

Comment: Please clarify what it is you are trying to do. Show an example string and the expected results of your loop.

Comment: Please get into the habit of writing comparisons as `variable === staticValue` (`i === 10`) and not `staticValue === variable` (`10 === i`).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll adjust what I've been working on to that structure. I'm new to coding, so I'm still learning what habits to develop.

Comment: This question is still not clear. Please provide a simple example of what `str` might be and what you hope to be able to get from your loop. Try to explain it in basic terms without code. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ah, I think I understand what you're trying to do: you want to do multiple tests, and return one variable that includes the results of multiple tests? You'd normally use an `object` for this, for example something like `var results = {}` then `results.testA = true`, `results.testB = false` then you can `return result` and look up testA and testB. If you're doing a beginner course, you'll get to objects soon :-)

Comment: Just do `str[2] === '{' && str[6] === '}'` or something similar?  Or use a regular expression. I don't understand why you want to iterate over the string.

Comment: Are you saying that you simply want to test for particular characters at particular positions within a string?

Comment: Yes. I understand how to test for  one type of character in set positions within a string, but was trying to see if it is possible to test for multiple characters in different positions within the same string.

Comment: So, can you just give us an example of what the set of characters you want to find would be and then an example of what the string to be tested might look like?

Comment: For example, if the user were to type in something like xxx{xx}xxx into a form it would return true because they typed the objects into the correct set positions, but if it was typed in as x{xxxxxx}, it would return as false because the objects were typed into the wrong positions.

Comment: This scenario seems like it would be best solved with an entirely different approach. So the question is, are you interested in an answer to your original question or an answer on how to accomplish your goal mentioned in your last comment?